# mkdir: Permission denied in /usr/lib with root user

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, root

I was trying to do apt upgrade what exceeded with some errors. Now, I found the reason why: Even root cannot write to */usr/lib* and can create */usr/lib/policykit-1* what is necessary for *packagekit*

But why? At least root should be able to write in every directory, right?

I'm running Debian 11 on a vServer. This error appeared unexpectedly and isn't disappearing after rebooting multiple times or doing stuff like apt autoremove (this exceeds in a similar error).

**apt update**

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 packagekit : Hängt ab von: policykit-1 ist aber nicht installiert
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

**apt --fix-broken install**

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeiten werden korrigiert … Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libappstream4 libdw1 libglib2.0-bin libgstreamer1.0-0 libpackagekit-glib2-18
  libstemmer0d libunwind8 linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64 packagekit
  packagekit-tools python3-dbus python3-distro-info
  python3-software-properties unattended-upgrades
Verwenden Sie »apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  policykit-1
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
  policykit-1
0 aktualisiert, 1 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
2 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 96,7 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 335 kB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
(Lese Datenbank ... 43174 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../policykit-1_0.105-31+deb11u1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von policykit-1 (0.105-31+deb11u1) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/policykit-1_0.105-31+deb11u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 Fehler beim Anlegen des Verzeichnisses »./usr/lib/policykit-1«: Die Operation ist nicht erlaubt
dpkg-deb: Fehler: »einfügen«-Unterprozess wurde durch Signal (Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)) getötet
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/policykit-1_0.105-31+deb11u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you have some good ideas? If you need more informations, let me know!

Regards!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, root may have limited access in these cases:

- Partition being full (data part or even inode table, e.g. with too many zero sized files)
- Partition being read-only (ro flag set, hardware issues, ...)
- Wrong attributes (check folders with lsattr)
- Some sort of kernel lock or quota applied on disk
- various other issues with running apps, zombies, ...

Restart with a clean boot into single mode and check things out from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

<code>
--------------e------- /usr/include
--------------e------- /usr/local
--------------e------- /usr/libexec
--------------e------- /usr/src
-----------I--e------- /usr/sbin
--------------e------- /usr/games
----i---------e------- /usr/lib
--------------e------- /usr/share
--------------e------- /usr/aa
--------------e------- /usr/libx32
--------------e------- /usr/lib32
--------------e------- /usr/lib64
-----------I--e------- /usr/bin
</code>

How do I make a clean boot?

Comment: The `e` (extended format) flag is expected, the `i` (immutable) flag on the other hand makes a directory unwritable, which is on your `/usr/lib` indeed. Use `sudo chattr -i /usr/lib` to solve.

Comment: I didn't know this thing before, but your command was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!